# Safecracker: Use a select dropdown to enter a text field?

Tags: safecracker

An easy one here, I think!

I have a channel field that is a text field. This field holds a numerical value, (between 1-12)

I am creating a safecracker form to add entires from the front end. Can I use a select drop down with the values 1-12 to complete this text field or does the actual channel field need to be a dropdown type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.

```
<select name="your_custom_field_name">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

And if you're using safecracker to edit, this is what I use:

```
<select name="your_custom_field_name">
  <option value="1"{if '{your_custom_field_name}'=='1'} selected{/if}>1</option>
  <option value="2"{if '{your_custom_field_name}'=='2'} selected{/if}>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not directly tested but I'm fairly sure it's no problem to use a dropdown field on the front-end via a safecracker form to pass that value. Both a regular text input and the select boxes rely on the `value` parameter and this will be what's sent through on form submission so it should be fine.